# Keep connection with SFTP server active on Ubuntu 18 File Explorer (Nautilus)

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssh, sftp

I'm trying to keep mounted an SFTP server on Ubuntu 18.04 Nautilus.

I tried to add to the `~/.ssh/config` file the following lines:

```
Host my.sftp.server
    Hostname my.sftp.server
    Port 22
    User myusername
    ServerAliveInterval 60
    ServerAliveCountMax 100
```

But the connection keeps falling after a certain amount of time. This is annoying when I perform some operations using a local terminal connected to the remote folder in the server.

Comment: Have you tried adding TCPKeepAlive yes ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've used these settings for years and my sftp/ssh connections stay up for days with ...

```
ServerAliveCountMax 5
ServerAliveInterval 15
TCPKeepAlive yes
```

... shorter alive intervals keep most nats & firewalls from closing seemingly idle connections.  60 seconds is too long for many use cases.  YMMV with ServerAliveCountMax.  At some point, you'll have to start tuning kernel parameters but you rarely have the option of doing that on both ends.  So, 5/15 works best for me with the default TCP settings.  TCPKeepAlive helps, too.  Unless, of course, there's a network device in the middle that got manually 'tuned' improperly.

You'll also want to ensure sftp is honoring your config settings, because they're host specific.  Try running with `sftp -vvv` to be sure.

Another option is [sshfs](https://github.com/libfuse/sshfs)